# Two questions on measure thory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $g(x)$ be a positive,measure function.$E$ is a measurable set.

First question:How can we get $m(E)=0$ from 
$$\int_{E}gdx=0$$
Second question:If $f\in L^1(g)$,namely $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|gdx< \infty$,then how can we prove $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$,namely $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|dx< \infty$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ Let $E_n= \{g\geq \frac{1}{n}\}\cap E$ and note that $E=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ since $g$ is positive and $E_n\subseteq E_{n+1}$ . Thus, by continuity of measures from below, we have $m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(E_n)$. However,

$$
0\leq m(E_n)=n\int_{E_n}\frac{1}{n}\textrm{d}m\leq n\int_{E_n}g\textrm{d}m\leq n\int_{E} g\textrm{d}m=0,
$$
where in the last inequality, we again used that $g$ is positive. We conclude that $m(E_n)=0$ for every $n$.

$b)$ It doesn't follow. Say $n=1$ and $g(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot 1_{|x|\geq 1} (x)$ and $f\equiv 1$. Then, $f\in L^1(g)$, but $f\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. You need to know more about $g$ (it should suffice that $g\not \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$), or you need to know the statement for a larger class of positive, measurable functions.

Comment: Thank you! Your proof help me a lot!